# Ошибка с dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var list = App.DB.Employees.ToList();

        membersDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
        update();
    }

    public void update()
    {
        var list = App.DB.Employees.ToList();
        
       
        var poisk = findinDB.Text;

        if (poisk != null)
        {
            list = App.DB.Employees.Where(p => p.name.Contains(poisk)).ToList();
        }
        
        membersDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Появляется такая ошибка, не могу понять в чем проблема, в другом проекте с той же бд, все работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста вставляйте текстовую информацию текстом, а не скриншотами.

Comment: Создайте обработчик события `Window.Loaded` и перенесите свой код в него, никогда не пишите свой код в конструкторе окна.